# How to access the state outside BlocConsumer and BlocCubit?

Tags: flutter, state, flutter-bloc, flutter-cubit

I am facing this weird issue, where though I have set the state, but the value when accessed  in init state is showing null !!

`user_cubit.dart`

```
  UserCubit() : super(UserInitialState()) {
    emit(UserMainLoadingState());
    _firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(_currentUser?.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      event.exists
          ? {
              emit(UserExists(
                  userModel: UserModel.fromjson(event.data()!, event.id)))
            }
          : {print("There is no such user"), emit(UserNotExists())};
    });
  }
```

`user_state.dart`

```
class UserState extends Equatable {
  final UserModel? userModel;
  const UserState({this.userModel});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [userModel];
}

class UserExists extends UserState {
  UserExists({required UserModel userModel}) : super(userModel: userModel) {
    print("I am inside the UserExists state and the user is :$userModel");
  }
}
```

`myWidget.dart`

```
  @override
  void initState() {
     _userState = const UserState();
    print("I am inside the initState The value of userstate is ${_userState.userModel}");  // This prints null , but why ? 
    if (_userState.userModel != null) {
     print("user is ${_userState.userModel.toString()}"); 
     }
    super.initState();
  }
```

Console log:

```
I/flutter ( 5029): I am inside the UserExists state and the user is :avatar boy
I/flutter ( 5029):  fullName krrrt
I/flutter ( 5029):  dob 19/1/2022
I/flutter ( 5029):  email rd@xddf.co
I/flutter ( 5029):  phone 12222222255

I/flutter ( 5029): I am inside the initState The value of userstate is null
```

Though the `userState's` `userModel` has value, why can't i access that in the `initState`.

// Ignore this, this is for stackoverflow.

// Ignore this, this is for stackoverflow.

// Ignore this, this is for stackoverflow.

// Ignore this, this is for stackoverflow.

// Ignore this, this is for stackoverflow.

Comment: the UserState() you are assigning is all together a new instance of the class. It will be null. Try using context.read to access the state from the cubit.

Comment: My state is not defined in the cubit, it is defined in the state @KrishBhanushali

Answer (score 0):

To access the state of a BLoC or Cubit in Flutter, you can use the `context.read<Bloc>()`. This method returns a Bloc instance that you can use to access the current state.

```dart
initState() {
  super.initState();

  _userState = const context.read<UserCubit>().state();
  print("I am inside the initState The value of userstate is ${_userState.userModel}");  // This prints null , but why ?
  if (_userState.userModel != null) {
    print("user is ${_userState.userModel.toString()}");
  }
}
```

---